# How to update session information in node js

Tags: node.js, session, passport.js, passport-local

I am using passport.js for session management and mysql for database.

I have multiple companies for the user. and user have different role in each company.
I am storing user roles in the session for the default company. because i have implemented various permission based on user role in the backend.

req.user will give me following response

```
req.user = {
  id: 2,
  user_name: 'akamboj1@yopmail.com',
  firstname: 'akamboj1',
  lastname: 'akamboj1',
  email_id: 'akamboj1@yopmail.com',
  user_access_token: 'a5049f367613d36eb7e20e9a1f4d4b36',
  is_active: 1,
  created_at: 2018-02-27T05:36:18.000Z,
  user_image: 'profile/images/default.png',
  roles: '2,3,4,5,8' }
```

I want to change the user roles in the session when user switch to other company.

Here is my passport serialize and deserialize  method

```
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        done(null, user.token);
    });

    // used to deserialize the user
    passport.deserializeUser(function (accessToken, done) {
        user.getUserByAccessToken(accessToken, function (err, dbUser) {
            if (err) {
                done(err);
            } else {
                done(null, dbUser[0]);
            }
        });
    });
```

Any Idea how can i update the session value?